# XCTestExpectation does not seem to work in Task()

Tags: swift, async-await, task, xctest, ios15

Im trying to run a test `actor` that makes a network request and if you call it while it still has a request going it will cancel the first request and throw an `CancellationError`. Im using a `Task()` to simulate it being called twice asynchrony and the code seems to be working fine. I can see the correct error being thrown and the `catch`-block being executed. Below is the code.

```
func testCancellation() async throws {
    //setup code

    let expectation = XCTestExpectation(description: "Cancellation Error thrown")
    let autocompleteHandler = AutocompleteHandler(session: session)
        
    Task() {
        do {
            let _ = try await autocompleteHandler.autocomplete(query: "Grizzly Bear")
        } catch {
            if error is CancellationError { expectation.fulfill() }
        }
    }
    Task() {
        do {
            let _ = try await autocompleteHandler.autocomplete(query: "Grizzly Bear")
        } catch {
            if error is CancellationError { expectation.fulfill() }
        }
    }
        
    wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 1)
}
```

When running this I get the following error:

```
Asynchronous wait failed: Exceeded timeout of 1 seconds, with unfulfilled expectations: "Cancellation Error thrown".
```

But as I said. I can see the `catch`-block being executed and the `error` is of the correct type and `expectation.fulfill()` is being called.

Comment: You're mixing system here. There's not need to use expectations to wait to see if something happened. Since your test function itself is `async`, you can just `await` on your async code, and then right your assertions about the result. See https://mokacoding.com/blog/how-to-test-async-await-code-in-swift/

Comment: But to more directly answer your question: this seems to be working as expected. You're expecting to see if a `CancellationError` is thrown, but you haven't done anything to suggest a `CancellationError` *should* be thrown

Comment: Disregard this question. It looks like its my code and not the testing framework that is the problem. Who would have thought!? :)

Comment: Why did yo udelete your answer? it's great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the comment from @Alexander I realized that I do indeed not need to wait for anything. I reformatted the code to the following and now it works.

```
func testCancellation() async {
    //Setup code

    let autocompleteHandler = AutocompleteHandler(session: session)
        
    async let first = autocompleteHandler.autocomplete(query: "Grizzly Bear")
    async let second = autocompleteHandler.autocomplete(query: "Grizzly Bear")
        
    do {
        let _ = [try await first, try await second]
        XCTFail("Should have thrown cancellation error")
    } catch {
        XCTAssert(error is CancellationError)
    }
}
```

This works as expected.